# A very strange issue, can not access to Localhost with WAMP after windows10 automatic upgrade

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

I got a very strange problem with the WAMP yesterday after windows automatic upgrade.

My WAMP started successfully, the icon is green

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT5w1.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9nSG.png)

Port 80 is used by httpd.exe.
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOA18.png)

Hosts file point localhost to 127.0.0.1 and::1

httpd.conf file
Listen [::1]:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using the WAMP Version 3.1.3 - 32bit
Windows 10

**No Skype, No iis in my laptop**

Everything looks fine, but just can not access to localhost and localhost/PHPMyAdmin and other sub virtual domains

I just can access the login page of localhost, can not access phpinfo neither, I used this more than one year, but happend yesterday.

Who can help me...........

Comment: let me know whether the server and other services are starting, without interruption?

Comment: no others started, just wampapache, wampmysql, dnscache